# Git not longer identified by terminal

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project for many weeks now and I'm having this error when trying to add new changes to git, suddenly:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

My terminal is not recognizing my project as a git repository anymore, so it's not running git commands. I know I could create a new one by running git init, but would that restart of all my branch progress on Github from zero if I push it? If so, is there still a way to push it without losing track?

Comment: The root directory should have its `.git` folder. Is it still here?

Comment: Which directory is your repository in? What directory is the current directory in your terminal?

Comment: @RomainValeri There's no git folder on my local root repository. Only a .gitattributes file. But still, it was working the whole time, until now. I don't remember deleting anything related to it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm in the right folder of the project. I can run it locally from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been through this recently when cloning an older commit, making new changes and trying to re-push it. Git wasn't recognizing my project anymore.

What solved it for me was, instead of cloning it using the HTTPS URL as usual, I've used the SSH one (which is password protected by an SHH key). With that, I've made the needed changes and pushed it to the existing repository, instead of initializing a new one and losing my commit history.

It must an issue related the token authentication system provided by Github:
https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/

Hope that works for you as well. Let me know.

Comment: That did it! I saw that article before but I was still clueless. Didn't realize that the SHH cloning method would make git recognize my cloned project, considering I don't have a git folder in my tree structure. That saved me a lot of time. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

The cause of issue could be that

- The project you are working upon is not a git versioned project at all.
- You may be at a higher folder for your project path which is not a git versioned folder.

Things to try:

- If the project is not git versioned. Go to the root folder of project and do a `git init` and `git add .` and `git commit -m "Initial commit"` and your project will be git versioned.
- Go the the project root folder and then try git commands.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not sure I wanna do this cause I think that may overwrite my existing GitHub project from zero.

Comment: NOTE: Create code copy before you try this.
If your github project has some history then it is possible to commit your current changes in one single commit. One thing that you may try is checkout the project from github in a seperate folder and then copy the .git folder from current checkout to the project you are working on and see if that helps.

Comment: Also it depends upon how much have you committed locally and not sync-ed to your remote repo.

Comment: I can't find any git folder on my project, even after running ls -la. And it was still working normally. Suddenly, it's "not a git repository" after weeks of pushing code.